# PHP if...elseif....else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Hoping someone can hep with this...

I have four logos, I want a three of them to display if a user is on a certain page and I want the fourth logo to display if the user is on any other page.

I just can't get my head round conditional statements?

```
if (is_page('870')
  Show logo 1;
elseif (is_page('891')
  Show logo 2;
elseif (is_page('886')
  Show logo 3;
else
  Show logo 4;
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: you really should read the manual first...

Comment: ... other than missing three close parentheses ...

Comment: how a bout switch case default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!page4) {
  // show logo 1, 2, and 3
} else {
   // show logo 4
}
```

Perhaps, I misunderstand your grammar. You are missing parenthesis.

```
if (is_page('870')) 
  Show logo 1;
else if (is_page('891'))
  Show logo 2;
else if (is_page('886'))
  Show logo 3;
else
  Show logo 4;
```